# How to redirect to another page if logged in through iFrame?

Tags: redirect, iframe

I have an HTML website with an internal iFrame page.  This iFrame loads a member's web page (php if it matters). I need the main HTML page to be redirected to another link after people login from within the iFrame. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you using iFrames? But anyways, just use `window.top.location.href = "http://www.site.com"; `

Comment: I use iframes because members site is php and hard to design the way I want. I dont know where to enter that code, and what has to do with my needs ? How that code will identify that people are logged on iframe site?

Comment: I pasted the code in html file but nothing happent after logged in, it  does not load the preset page.

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve my problem please ? I just need parent page to be redirected to other page only after users login in iframe.

Comment: Try taking out the `.href`. Or use `top.location.replace("http://blah.com");`.

Comment: I tried with no results. Do you have an email to send you my cpanel details. I'am sure its more easy for you and you will get a better picture.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's not a hosting issue, if that's what you mean. Have you tested it in other browsers?

Comment: Not hosting issue but more like personal experience issue. That is why I rather give you acces to change file yourself. So, I have a website www.mysite.com , inside that I have the iframe (which loads from www.mysite.com/iframe) . Iframe its a job site so people must login. After they login in iframe I need parent site to be redirected to another link. I pasted to code you gave me in the parent site html code, then I tried to login in iframe to see if parent site is redirected but nothing happens (and the code its shown in the browser).

Comment: You're always welcome to email me, but are you able to upload it to http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: sorry,it was blocked only for my IP. please try now.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You're supposed to put a function that calls for `window.top.location = "http://www.site.com";` within the login form of the website within the iFrame.

Comment: Problem solved. I was entering the code in the wrong file. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you, but I'm glad to see that you've figured it out. I'll just answer the question so you can close it.

Comment: Well, thank you, I would be very happy if you can give me some help o other problem to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771750/i-need-search-text-in-parent-search-box-but-to-search-in-iframe-of-another-link.

Answer (score 0):

Put `window.top.location = "http://www.site.com";`.