# I need search text in parent search box but to search in iframe of another link and post results there

Tags: search

I have a html home parent template with 2 search boxes for jobs (people must enter job type and city manually). I need search text from the 2 boxes to be forwarded to other link, in search boxes within the iframe of that new link. When people push SEARCH button new link will be loaded with search results in iframe.

All its on the same domain.

This are parent search boxes and button : jsfiddle.net/rAgSt

Answer (score 0):

Assign the searched result contains variable to first page of empty div using javascript(HTMLElement **innerHTML** Property).

For Example:
In first Page div like this,

```
<div id="searchedresults"></div>
```

In iframe page ,javascript codes for assigning searched result,

```
document.getElementById('searchedresults').innerHTML=results;
```

Comment: I have no experience. Would you please add the need it code yourself for iframe here http://jsfiddle.net/eJ6XK/1/ and parent html here http://jsfiddle.net/rAgSt     Thank you